# Dr. Java System.out.println shortcut

Tags: shortcut, drjava

I am currently in a situation where I am using Dr. Java, and I can not find a `sysout` style shortcut for the `System.out.println`. Is there an equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

I've also been searching for any existing shortcut, similar to the one the Eclipse IDE has. But unfortunately, DrJava doesn't seem to have this option (even with the most recent release: `drjava-beta-2019-220051`).

However, if you enter in the `Key Bindings` option menu `(Edit -> Preferences -> Key Bindings)`, you can enable the `Auto-Complete Word Under Cursor` option.

The default key shortcut is `CTRL + SHIFT + Space`,  but you can also modify it to your preferred option. It is basically an autocomplete that has most of Java API reserved words.

If it seems more efficient for you while typing, you can just start with `Sys`, use the shortcut, and select the desired word from the list that appears. Hope it helps.